# RxJS version 6 operators change?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

It used to be I could so something like this:

```
const rs = new ReplaySubject();
rs.take(1).subscribe(v => {});
```

but it looks like the API changed to:

```
const rs = new ReplaySubject();
rs.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(v => {});
```

https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

is this right? Seems like a big change and I don't understand that rationale.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#why

Comment: it's now used to implement compose operator, it's more cleaner and easy to read, as they suggest.

Comment: ok that's cool, if you can just add an answer that the old way won't work at all, and you have to use the pipe operator that would help other people thanks